# Why isn't $x^2+x+1$ a factor of $x^{12}+x^6+1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, roots, factoring

When we solve the equation
$$x^{12}+x^6+1=0$$ we obtain $2$ solutions that also satisfy $$x^2+x+1=0$$
namely $-\frac{1}{2}\pm i\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$.
Shouldn't this imply that $x^2+x+1$ is a factor of $x^{12}+x^6+1$? However, the fully factorsied form of
$x^{12}+x^6+1$ is $$(x^6-x^3+1)(x^6+x^3+1)$$
The reason I think that it should be a factor is that when we have, for a function $f(x)$, (here a polynomial,) $f(a)=0$ then we know that $(x-a)$ is a factor of $f(x)$.

If we multiply $(x-(-\frac{1}{2}+ i\frac{\sqrt3}{2}))$ by $(x-(-\frac{1}{2}- i\frac{\sqrt3}{2}))$ which are both factors of $x^{12}+x^6+1$ we get $x^2+x+1$. It seems to me that this should apply to the polynomials above. I have a feeling that my logic is specious, but I'm not entirely certain why; I think the answer to my problem may be that $x^2+x+1$ is factor of $x^{12}+x^6+1$, but only if the other factor has complex coefficients, but I'm not sure. Thank you for your help.

**EDIT**
Oh wow, I'm so sorry for making such a stupid mistake everyone, thanks for correcting me (see numerous comments and answers). I was looking at a few polynomials simultaneously and got mixed up. Thanks for your help.

Comment: $x^3\equiv1\pmod{x^2+x+1}$ so $x^{12}+x^6+1\equiv1+1+1=3\pmod{x^2+x+1}$.

Comment: I used polynomial division and got that they are not divisible by each other.

Comment: @AnginaSeng is that a proof that $x^{12}+x^6+1$ has a non-zero remainder when divided by $x^2+x+1$? Apologies, I am not extremely familiar with modular arithemtic.

Comment: The real parts of the roots of $x^{12}+x^6+1$ are not $-0.5$. How did you get this result ?

Comment: @NoahD. thanks so much for spending the time to help me! Is it possible then that the other factor, if it exists, has complex coefficients?

Comment: Side note: setting $z = x^6$, the original equation becomes $z^2+z+1=0$. You know the roots of this latter equation; then take their sixth roots to find the roots of the original.

Comment: $$\text{If } x = \dfrac{-1 + i\sqrt 3} 2 \text{ then } x^{12} = 1 \text{ and } x^6=1, \text{ so } x^{12} + x^6 + 1 = 3. $$

Comment: Oh wow, I'm so sorry everyone for making such a stupid mistake, thanks for correcting me. I was looking at a few polynomials simultaneously and got mixed up. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Note that $x^{12}+x^6+1=(x^{12}-1)+(x^6-1)+3=(x^6-1)(x^6+1+1)+3=(x^3-1)(x^3+1)(x^6+2)+3=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)(x^3+1)(x^6+2)+3$. This is easier to do by polynomial modular arithmetic, but there is some interest in the detail.

Comment: By the way, I would not delete a post which has generated such a range of constructive answers and comments - this material may be of value to someone else. One of the points of the site is to be a repository of good answers on the mathematical questions people actually have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct that if all of the roots of a polynomial $f(x)$ are roots of a polynomial $g(x)$, then $f(x)$ is a factor of $g(x)$.

However $x^2 + x + 1$ is not a factor of $x^{12} + x^6 + 1$. The reason is because $- \frac{1}{2} \pm i \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ are not roots of that polynomial. This is because

$$ \left( - \frac{1}{2} \pm i \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \right)^3 = 1,$$

so plugging it into $x^{12} + x^6 + 1$ gives $(x^3)^4 + (x^3)^2 + 1 = 1 + 1 + 1 = 3 \neq 0$.

Comment: Oh wow, I'm so sorry for making such a stupid mistake, thanks for correcting me. I was looking at a few polynomials simultaneously and got mixed up. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @A-levelStudent Happy to help. It's good you thought about this question carefully and correctly reasoned that $x^2 + x + 1$ "should have" divided $x^{12} + x^6 + 1$ if its roots had been roots of $x^{12} + x^6 + 1$. Algebra mistakes happen, they're a fact of life, but proofs are forever :)

Comment: Thanks for the consolation :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry, but I don't know how you arrived at your assertion that $-1/2 \pm i \sqrt{3}/2$ are roots of $x^{12} + x^6 + 1$.  In fact, we note $$-\frac{1}{2} \pm i \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} = e^{\pm 2\pi i/3},$$ hence $$(e^{\pm 2\pi i/3})^{12} + (e^{\pm 2\pi i/3})^6 + 1 = 1 + 1 + 1 = 3 \ne 0.$$

Comment: Oh wow, I'm so sorry for making such a stupid mistake, thanks for correcting me. I was looking at a few polynomials simultaneously and got mixed up. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Should I delete my question?

Comment: It's fine. It may benefit others.

Answer (score 2):

@AnginaSeng has already proved dividing $p(x):=x^{12}+x^6+1$ by $x^2+x+1$ leaves a remainder of $3$.

In thinking the remainder would be $0$, you seem to have misindentified the roots of $p$. Since $x^6=\exp\frac{\pm2\pi i}{3}$, $x=\exp\frac{\pm\pi i}{9}\exp\frac{n\pi i}{3}$ for $n\in\{0,\,1,\,2,\,3,\,4,\,5\}$. You can verify, e.g. by working modulo $\frac{\pi i}{9}$, that none of these $12$ roots' phases matches either root of $x^2+x+1$, which would be $\exp\frac{\pm 2\pi i}{3}=\exp\frac{\pm6\pi i}{9}$.

Comment: Oh wow, I'm so sorry for making such a stupid mistake, thanks for correcting me. I was looking at a few polynomials simultaneously and got mixed up. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Should I delete my question?

Comment: @A-levelStudent I don't think you can at this stage, not that I'd advise it even if you could. This question can still be of value to others later, even if it resulted from "stupidity". [You have other options](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question) that are worth learning about, though.

Answer (score 2):

Another issue besides that mentioned by several posters in both answers and comments is this: You say the "the fully factorsied form" is a certain product of two cubic polynomials with integer coefficients. But if that is "the fully factorsied form", that would mean that's as much factoring as can be done with integer coefficients. With complex coefficients, a cubic can be factored further.

Comment: So my description was incorrect? Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @A-levelStudent : In some contexts your description would be correct. But $\Big( x - \frac{-1 + i\sqrt 3} 2\Big)$ would be among the factors of any polynomial of which $\frac{-1+i\sqrt 3} 2$ is a zero. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

I just want to note a technique based on my comment to the original post where a factor of $x^2+x+1$ can be shown longhand for $x^{2n}+x^n+1$ where $n$ is not a multiple of $3$.

Suppose $n=3m+1$ then $$x^{6m+2}+x^{3m+1}+1=x^{6m+2}-x^2+x^{3m+1}-x+x^2+x+1=$$$$=x^2\left(x^{6m}-1\right)+x\left(x^{3m}-1\right)+x^2+x+1$$ and the two bracketed terms are divisible by $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$

With $n=3m+2$ we have similarly $$x^{6m+4}+x^{3m+2}+1=x^{6m+4}-x+x^{3m+2}-x^2+x^2+x+1=$$$$=x\left(x^{6m+3}-1\right)+x^2\left(x^{3m}-1\right)+x^2+x+1$$ and a factor $x^3-1$ is there for the two bracketed terms.

The various other methods are more efficient, but this is direct.